# Elasticsearch query containing multiple search criterias

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch to store HTTP-log data in the following format:

```
{
    "domain": "www.vg.no", 
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1", 
    "timestamp": "2014-03-19T15:58:18", 
    "destination_ip": "195.88.54.16", 
    "referer": "http://www.vg.no/path/example.exe", 
    "destination_port": "80", 
    "response_length": "4808", 
    "response_code": "200", 
    "source_ip": "192.1.1.1", 
    "uri": "/bil-og-motor/css/topp_artikkel2_bilogmotor.jpg", 
    "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36", 
    "source_port": "63894", 
    "method": "GET"
}
```

I'm trying to build a query where I can fetch data that matches user made criterias with the following options:
domain, search string that may match any field, the uri includes a file extension, the timestamp is within a defined timerange.

Example:

- *Domain* = "www.vg.no",
- *_all* includes "*1.1*",
- *uri* = "*.exe",
- *timestamp* between "2014-03-19T00:00" and "2014-03-19T23:59"

I've tried to make this query several times without success. I'd become really happy if somebody could help me :)

**Update:**
This is how I insert the records using python:

```
es.index(
  index="test",
  doc_type="http_log",
  body={
   'timestamp' : self.request.timestamp,
   'domain' : self.request.domain,
   'uri' : self.request.uri,
   'user_agent' : self.request.user_agent,
   'referer' : self.request.referer,
   'method' : self.request.method,
   'protocol' : self.request.protocol,
   'response_code' : self.response.code,
   'response_length' : self.response.length,
   'source_ip' : self.request.source_ip,
   'source_port' : self.request.source_port,
   'destination_ip' : self.request.destination_ip,
   'destination_port' : self.request.destination_port
 }
)
```

Comment: Can you also post the mapping, this very important with these kind of queries. It is also wise to check the mapping per field to see what is happening with your data. By the way you can create a bool query to accomplish this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Jettro. Im totally new to Elasticsearch and is not familiar with how mapping works. Therefore, I have not specified any explicit way to map the documents so I assume that ES is using some kind of default mapping?

I will change the mapping if necessary. Any suggestions?

Comment: Without a mapping this is a hard problem. Some things that do not work for now. Searching on .exe, try example.exe this works. The dates you provide also have a problem, they are missing seconds and therefore will not map to dates by default. You have to do some research to the required mappings that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure the mapping for the timestamp is date_time field..For different date time formats in elaticsearch click [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html)

Now first search for search text in all the fields and then filter out the results based on domain and date.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/http_log/_search' -d '
      {
"query": {
    "query_string": {
       "query": "search text"
    }
},
"filter": {
    "and": {
       "filters": [
          {
              "query": {
                  "wildcard": {
                     "uri": {
                        "value": "*.exe"
                     }
                  }
              }
          },
          {
              "query": {
                  "match_phrase": {
                     "domain": "www.vg.no"
                  }
              }
          },
          {
              "range": {
                 "timestamp": {
                    "from":"2014-03-19T00:00",
                    "to": "2014-03-19T23:59"
                 }
              }
          }
       ]
    }
}'
```